# Form doesn't submit values in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5. Here, when i click on the search bar it calls the java script function, and when i provide the searchString value to the form, and click SUBMIT, it doesn't submit anything. Why is that?

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('a[href="#search"]').on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#search').addClass('open');
            $('#search > form > input[type="search"]').focus();
        });

        $('#search, #search button.close').on('click keyup', function (event) {
            if (event.target == this || event.target.className == 'close' || event.keyCode == 27) {
                $(this).removeClass('open');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

View:

```
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                @Html.ActionLink("TimeEntry", "Index", "TimeEntry", null, new {@class = "navbar-brand"})
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.ActionLink("TimeEntry", "Login", "User", null, new {@class = "navbar-brand"})
            }

        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Clock In/Out(WIP)", "Index", "TimeEntry")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Time Summary", "BackEnd", "TimeEntry")</li>



                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Users", "Index", "User")</li>
                <li><a href="#search">Search</a></li>


            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    <li> @Html.ActionLink("Log Out", "Logout", "User")</li>

                }
            </ul>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="search">
    <button type="button" class="close" style="padding-top: 35px">x</button>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "User", FormMethod.Get))
    {
            @Html.TextBox("searchString","", new {@placeholder = "Search by First Name"})
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Search Rando</button>   
    }
</div>

<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr/>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My TimeClock Application</p>
    </footer>
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your cancelling the `submit` event (twice!) - `event.preventDefault();` and `return false;`

Comment: If you want to submit the form, don't cancel it! (remove the last block of code starting with `$('form').submit(function (event) {`. But you have not shown your view so its difficult to understand what your really trying to do here.

Comment: @StephenMuecke : i will post the view.

Comment: I don't understand the issue. What do you mean by _the submission works, but not when it is used in the razor file_? Are you wanting to update the current page based on the value of `searchString`? (rather than post and redirect) - in which case you would use ajax

Comment: When i use the javascript code, i can log in, i.e. clicking on the log in button does nothing, but when i remove this script it works.

Comment: What 'login' button are you referring to? And why would you have a 'login' button anyway (if you want a user to be authorized for this page, mark the method with the `[Authorize]` attribute)

Comment: You can't just change the code in your question - none of the comments now make sense! Please roll back you last edit. And if you have _found the error_, then you can add an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

This line is cancelling the default event action.  Take it out to allow the form to submit.

```
event.preventDefault();
```

This will allow the form to submit.  Although the other two lines in that function will no longer serve any purpose, since they are modifying the state of the document, but the browser will navigate away from the document as soon as the form submission happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Search Rando</button>
```

should be changed to

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search Rando</button>
```

by altering the `type` to `submit`